# Normalizing a given matrix to a matrix which column entries sum to 1 in C++

Tags: c++, loops

I am new to C++ and I am trying to normalize a matrix's column to sum to one with the use of for loops. This is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
double A[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
double sum = 0;
int r = 3;
int c = 3;
for (int j=0; j < c; j++) {
  for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {
    sum += A[i][j];
  }
  for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {
    A[i][j] /= sum;
  }
}
for (int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
  for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
      std::cout<<A[i][j];
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
0.0833333 0.333333 0.583333
0.0740741 0.185185 0.296296
0.0666667 0.133333 0.2
```

I am not sure why the output appears as it is, It seems that it worked for the first column but not the rest. Yet, the remaining two column remains in the same ratio. How can the code be modified so that I can "normalize" my matrix using for loop as intended?

Comment: If you need to sum the values in each column and then divide each value in the column by it. It works for the first time because the value of `sum` starts at 0. However, when it moves to the second column, there is an existing value of sum i.e. the total of the first column instead of just the `sum` of the next column. So once your second for loop ends `A[i][j]/=sum` assign `sum` a value of 0

Answer (score 1):

Suocle,

You're almost there with your code. One of the things that you forgot to consider is the fact that the variable `sum` continues to over time, sum the values present in the entire matrix and not just the values of the `column`

```
for (int j=0; j < c; j++) {
  for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {
    sum += A[i][j];
  }
  for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {
    A[i][j] /= sum;
  }
}
```

For the first iteration of the for loop i.e. for the 1st column, since the `sum` is zero it ends up getting the right sum of the values of the column and later normalizing it by doing the division of the sum with the values.

However, in the next iteration when looping through the 2nd column, the previous value of `sum` remains and hence must be assigned to `0` again at the end of the loop to get the new correct sum of `column 2` or else you have `sum=sum(column1)+sum(column2)` at this stage.

```
for (int j=0; j < c; j++) {
  for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {
    sum += A[i][j];
  }
  for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {
    A[i][j] /= sum;
  }
  sum = 0;
}
```

Comment: @C.Suocle , If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).